# setEmptyView and ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem. I want to do so if list is empty then created EmptyView, else if list include items then created ListView with elements from list.
How to do it?

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                  .............
        CrimeAdapter adapter = new CrimeAdapter(mCrimes);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
                  .............
}

@TargetApi(11)
@Override
public ListView onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

        ListView view = (ListView)parent.findViewById(R.id.list);
        view.setEmptyView(parent.findViewById(R.id.empty));
                ................        
        return view;
}

private class CrimeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Crime> 
{
    public CrimeAdapter(ArrayList<Crime> crimes) 
    {
        super(getActivity(), 0, crimes);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, null);
        }

        Crime c = getItem(position);

        TextView titleTextView =
            (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_titleTextView);
        titleTextView.setText(c.getTitle());
        TextView dateTextView =
            (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_dateTextView);
        dateTextView.setText(c.getDate().toString());
        CheckBox solvedCheckBox =
            (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_solvedCheckBox);
        solvedCheckBox.setChecked(c.isSolved());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

As there is xml file(list_and_empty_view.xml) which consist of ListView for list and View for emptyView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ListView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/is_empty" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: where is your xml for emptyView, kindly post it

Comment: @drWisdom i posted xml-file.

Comment: @rekrut is it a `ListFragment `or `Fragment`?

Comment: I have posted an answer, try it.

Comment: @KNeerajLal it is ListFragment

Comment: @drWisdom thank you, now try it.

Comment: It will help if you show the enclosing class.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I added enclosing class.

Comment: You still have two methods that are not contained in a class.

Answer (score 0):

Your EmptyView should have an id like this:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/empty"// id should be set like this.
        android:text="No Items Found"/>
```

and then you need to call `listView.setEmptyView()` after calling `listView.setAdapter()`.
and use `setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty)`.

Comment: If you use the correct `id`, there is no need to call `setEmptyView()`.

Comment: @drWisdom And the identifier of the list must also android:id="@android:id/list"?

Comment: not necessarily, if you use the setEmptyView() method, the list's id can be anything.

Comment: The `id` for the list is completely independent of the current discussion. This depends on whether you want to be able to use `getListView()` for the `ListFragment` or if you use `findViewById()` instead. This isn't the question at hand.

Comment: Also, if you use `setEmptyView()`, you can use whatever `id` you wish for the empty view. It no longer needs to be `android:id="@android:id/empty"`.

Comment: while on paper, what you are saying sounds logical (and this is what i thought before) but i couldn't get it to work this way. And by the way i was using listView in activity not ListFragment. Anyway now the question poster has more than one options.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [ListFragment documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html), you must use ids `"@android:id/list"` and `"@android:id/empty"`. (Note that there is a typo for the later in the documentation.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ListView>

        <View
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/is_empty" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: if you use the setEmptyView() method, the list's id can be anything, not necessarily @android:id/list.

Comment: @drWisdom The `id` for the list has absolutely nothing to do with whether you use `setEmpytView()` or not. These are two completely independent issues.